# How to Sort a List of Numbers Ignoring All Characters Except Number

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sorting

How to sort a list of numbers ignoring special characters.
For example:

`[45, 10, 15, 30, "18*"]` in which "18*" is a string and the rest are integers

I want it to sort like this:

```
[10, 15, "18*", 30, 45]
```

this is my whole code should you need it- it is for a number guessing game that tracks your guesses in a list and marks the right guess with an asterisk:

```
# 1. Generate random integer

import random 
randomNumber = random.randint( 1, 100 )

# 2. Take user input
guessList = []

userGuess = int( raw_input( "Guess an integer between 1 and 100\n> " ))
guessList.append(userGuess)

if userGuess == randomNumber:
    print( "Wow! First try!" )

# 4. High/low loop that terminates if user types "113" or guesses number



while userGuess != randomNumber and userGuess != 113:

    if userGuess > randomNumber:
        userGuess = int( raw_input( 'Your guess is too high! Guess another integer or type "113" to quit.\n> ' ))
        if userGuess != randomNumber:
            guessList.append(str(userGuess))

    if userGuess < randomNumber:
        userGuess = int( raw_input( 'Your guess is too low! Guess another integer or type "113" to quit.\n> ' ))
        if userGuess != randomNumber:
            guessList.append(str(userGuess))


# 5. Endgame outputs depending on if they user quit or guessed the number

if userGuess == 113:
    print ( "You have quit the game. Better luck next time." )

if userGuess == randomNumber:
    guessList.append( str(userGuess) + "*" )
    print ( " You guessed the number! You are a magician! Your guesses were: " )
    print ( guessList )
```

Please tell me what sorting algorithm I need to use.

Answer (score 0):

First, define a function to transform `str` to `int`:

```
def transform(item):
    """If item is int, return it unchanged. Otherwise it should be a string of
    one or more digits followed by '*'; strip '*' and return the digits as int.
    """
    return item if isinstance(item, int) else int(item.strip('*'))
```

Then pass the function as [the `key` argument](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) to the builtin `sorted`:

```
>>> ls = [45, 10, 15, 30, "18*"]
>>> sorted(ls, key=transform)
[10, 15, "18*", 30, 45]
>>> # list.sort also accepts a `key` argument
>>> ls.sort(key=transform)
>>> ls
[10, 15, "18*", 30, 45]
```

Comment: Go 3 downvotes so far. What's the reason, may I ask?